# How to prevent all links from redirecting before completing an AJAX process

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

I have an application that uses tinyMCE. In this page, the user will compose a message then previews it on another page (not using tinyMCE's preview). I currently have an AJAX function that saves the content when the user clicks away from the tinyMCE UI. The problem is, I have different kinds of links on this same page, sometimes when a user clicks on the link, the AJAX function fails to save the content before redirecting, thus resulting to a blank preview or unsaved message.

```
<div>
<textarea id='msg'></textarea>
<a id='preview'>Preview</a>
<a id='other_page'>Other Page</a>
<a id='another_page'>Another Page</a>
</div>
```

Here are the JavaScript handlers and functions.

```
    <script>
    // INITIALIZE TINYMCE
    tinyMCE.init({
    // SAVE CONTENT ON BLUR
            editor.on('blur', function() { save_message(this); });
    })

    function save_message(){
        var msg= tinyMCE.get('msg ').getContent();
         $.ajax({
                    statusCode : { 404: function(){alert('Not Found');} },
                    type       : 'post',
                    data       : {msg:msg},
                    url        : '<script_that_handles_save>',
                    success    : function(res){ // DO SOMETHING } 
            }); 
    }

// WHEN PREVIEW IS CLICKED
$('a.preview).click(function(){
          save_message();
});

$('a.other_page).click(function(){
          save_message();
});

$('a.another_page).click(function(){
          save_message();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused by the wording. Have you tried just using a JS redirect in the success handler of your $.ajax function instead of relying on the default anchor link functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, your `save_message()` function is an AJAX call that needs to complete and send back a response for it to work. When you click an anchor tag, the function is called (a per your code above) but the page redirects before the function returns a response.
Also it seems like you are calling the function redundantly for each anchor tag, why not call it once for ALL anchor tags, like so `a.click(function(){ // your function here });`

Your code logic is good, you only need to re-structure and simplify it, like so:

```
tinyMCE.init({
// SAVE CONTENT ON BLUR
        editor.on('blur', function() { save_message(this); });
})
$('a').click(function(e){
        // prevent the redirect
        e.preventDefault();
       var msg= tinyMCE.get('msg ').getContent();
       var location = $(this).attr('href');  
      // execute ajax
     $.ajax({
                statusCode : { 404: function(){alert('Not Found');} },
                type       : 'post',
                data       : {msg:msg},
                url        : '<script_that_handles_save>',
                success    : function(res){
                               // redirect on success
                              window.location.href = location
                         }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create some kind of flag variable, which will tell if links should be prevented from redirecting or not. Before sending AJAX request to save message, set this variable to `true`, and after successful request set it back to `false`. Also set an event listener on all links, which will check this flag variable, and if it equals `true`, prevent redirecting.

Example code:

```
var linksDisabled = false;

function save_message() {
  linksDisabled = true;
  $.ajax({
    success: function() {
      linksDisabled = false;
    }
    // some other options
  })
}

$("a").click(function(event) {
  if (linksDisabled) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: how does linksDisabled variable connects to my anchor tags?